# Dependency in Modules in terraform

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create datasets,tables and views in bigquery on gcp using terraform. i am using this module.

```
module “bigquery-tenant-datasets” {
for_each = var.tenant_datasets
source = “terraform-google-modules/bigquery/google”
version = “5.1.0”
dataset_id = each.value.datasetName
dataset_name = each.value.datasetName
description = each.value.datasetName
project_id = var.project_id
location = var.location
tables = [for table in var.tenant_tables: merge(table, {“schema”: file(table[“schema”])})]
views = [for view in var.tenant_views: merge(view, {“query”: replace(view[“query”], “tenantName”, each.value.datasetName)})]
dataset_labels = var.dataset_labels
}
```

The problem with this is the terraform currently needs to be ran multiple times, as the order of object creation is somewhat random…i.e views are tried to be created before tables exist. So it gave error sometimes.
What can i do here to resove this and ensure that tables are always created first and then views?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: Hey, @Marcin Yeah I was able to resolve this by adding a depends_on block inside the configuration of my module. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [depends_on](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/depends_on) to explicitly specify order of resources who depend on each other and which TF does not automatically order correctly.

Comment: Hello @marcin with terraform we can't use depends_on while creating resources using modules. We can use depends_on when using resource blocks to create resources.

Comment: @Himanshu No sure what you mean. Docs clearly write that depends_on is supported for modules. Have you even checked what I linked in the answer?